# C while loop not executing

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm learning c and I can't figure out the problem with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int i = 0;
while(i > 10){
    printf("hello");
    i++;
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I don't get any errors and have tried running it on codeblocks and wxdev c++. So is there something I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Think about what the condition in your `while` statement means...

Comment: Can `0` ever be greater than `10`?

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger... Stepping through that code would/should have led you through a thought process like "Hmm, why doesn't it enter this while loop? How can `(0 > 10)` be *false*? Oh, wait... d'oh!"

Answer (score 4):

You set

```
i = 0;
```

and then test

```
i > 10
```

which is always false.

You might want

```
while (i < 10)
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

I is not greater than 10 so it doesnt meet the requirement to enter the while loop

Comment: oh wow cant believe i didnt notice that thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
while(i > 10){
```

...but `i` is 0 so it's false and skips.

You probably meant to instead write;

```
while(i < 10) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason: `i` is not greater than 10.